# Group by numerical columns with a threshold of error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, matching

I have this dataframe,

**input**:

| DishID(string) | Recipe(string) | Pct(float) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | chicken | 0.5 |
| One | rice | 0.3 |
| One | tomatoes | 0.2 |
| two | chicken | 0.501 |
| two | rice | 0.3003 |
| two | tomatoes | 0.1999 |
| three | beef | 0.5 |
| three | rice | 0.4999 |
| four | beef | 0.5001 |
| four | rice | 0.499 |
| five | egg | 0.300 |
| five | tomatoes | 0.700 |

`Def Find_matching_recipe(Threshold = 0.01):`

**output desired**:
`[[One,Two],[Three,four],[Five]]`

With a threshold of error , group the *similar* dish according their recipe and the percentage corresponding.

I know how to do it for percentage that are exactly the same(Threshold=0), but I have no clue how to do it with a threshold of error.

It can be in SQL or pandas python.

Thank you for your help,
Don't hesitate if you have any question

Comment: Could you give us an example with `Threshold > 0` ?

Comment: In the example it is the case where the Threshold >0, If it where =0 

The dishID "one" and the dishID "two" wouldn't match. Threshold = 0 means perfect match in recipe AND pct